# NGINX: method for passing only one port through to reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have NGINX set up to listen on both 80 and 443. It worked fine and passed all traffic from both ports to port 7000 to get picked up by ASP.NET, so far so good.

Then I commented out some of the config (you can see below) because I *don't* want HTTP port 80 to actually go to 7000. I want it to be treated normally by NGINX so it can serve files in `/var/www`. But when I go to `http://somedomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html` it just gives 404 errors. I suspect it's still trying to go upstream. Any ideas on how to bypass the proxy for port 80 but keep it for 443?

```
upstream somedomain.com
{
    server 127.0.0.1:7000;
}

server
{
    server_name somedomain.com;

    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/somedomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/somedomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include                   /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam               /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml;
    gzip_proxied    no-cache no-store private expired auth;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gunzip on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://somedomain.com;
    }
}

server
{
    #if ($host = somedomain.com)
    #{
    #    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #}

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name somedomain.com;
    #return 404;

    root /var/www/somedomain.com;

    location / {
    }
}
```

The test.html file is in the correct location. It's worth mentioning also that /var/www/somedomain.com is where the ASP.NET files are too.

**Edit**
I think maybe part of the issue is that `http://somedomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html` keeps redirecting to `https://somedomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html`. So if this auto-secure-redirect can be fixed, perhaps the 404 error will go away..

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the answer was to add `default_server` in the second server block for port 80, and it starts working. Thanks everyone for your input!

```
server
{
    server_name somedomain.com;

    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/somedomain.com;
}
```